# AngularJS $location search confused

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This is my url with params look like:

```
http://localhost:8000/search?city=uk&cat=Sightseeing%20&%20Tours
```

But when I try to capture the `cat` params using:

```
var test2 = $location.search().cat;
```

it only return `Sightseeing`. How can I resolve this issues? Thanks!!

Comment: What do you expect cat to be? `Sightseeing & Tours`?

Comment: it seems like angular use regexp when it try to find something in url. Can you try use $location.search('cat') ?

Answer (score 1):

The ampersand (`&`) is the delimiter for URL parameters. This means that the `cat` parameter ends after `Sightseeing%20`. (The `%20` is probably automatically converted to a space, rendering it invisible.)

There is a simple solution though; just percent-encode the ampersand; use `%26`. Note most programming languages provide some function to automatically percent-encode strings, in PHP for example it would be `urlencode()`.

For more information, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding. It talks about reserved and unreserved characters in URLs, which is exactly what's causing your problem; the ampersand is a reserved character.